# Exchange Server 2007 Forwarding Circles

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs, mail-forwarding

I asked a question quite a while ago about two members of an organization who wanted to receive all of each other's emails, and yet maintain seperate mailboxes. (so all emails to mike@company get sent to mike and dave and all emails to dave@company get sent to mike and dave).

At the time, I actually only needed to implement one side of this (only mikes emails got sent to both receipients) and (with the help of ServerFault) I set up forwarding on dave's inbox so that all of his emails would also be sent to mike.

I'm now in a situation where I have to implement the other side of this relation (such that mike's emails will also forward to dave). I still remember how to set up the forwarding rule, but I'm worried that I might be creating a circular forwarding rule such that mike@compnay forwards to dave@company which forwards to mike@company and so on. Can anyone clear up my confusion (just want to make sure I don't make a stupid mistake). Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

Exchange 2003 will detect a forwarding loop and squash it. I'm assuming that this behavior has been carried forward (pun intended) in Exchange 2007.

My suggestion would be to create an Outlook rule in each mailbox that forwards email with the exception that it not forward email recieved from the other recipient (meaning email from you to Mike gets forwarded to Dave but email from Dave to Mike doesn't get forwarded to Dave, and vice versa for Mike).

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to think out some kind of complex hub transport rules that would edit the headers and check for that editing before delivering... but I think a simpler solution is in order. How about granting each user appropriate permissions to eachother's mailbox and then adding the other's mailbox to each user's profile.

Also, if you have sharepoint you might be able to create a mail enabled sharepoint group and share mail that way. Public folders, while deprecated, might also be applicable here. I think forwarding isn't going to work for you... unless I"m missing the obvious. Today seems to be an unusually dyslexic day for me.

<strike>**Don't use hub transport rules**. In each mailbox's properties window, go to the mailflow settings tab and then the delivery options properties. Click "Forward to:" and select the other user's mailbox. Make sure to click "Deliver message to both forwarding address and mailbox."</strike> (I fail)

Comment: This is what I've done for the first case... What I'm wondering is if I set this on both users, will it cause a loop between the two forwarding settings???

Comment: Gack. My mind double backed on itself. Editing post accordingly.